# Invalid preference page path: Security

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2, plugin.xml

I have an error when I launch my eclipse-rcp application:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-02-24 17:00:14.011
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: Security
```

What is it?
My application has p2.
I see that this error is correlated with the extension: org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages
The extension in my plugin.xml doesn't have either name and ID and has three pages that are also my classes.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `WorkbenchPreferenceManager.addExtension(...)`: When you define the hierarchy of your preference pages, you must specify the parent preference page via the ID of the parent. My guess is that you have use the name of the parent page instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the missing dependencies, org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui, org.eclipse.wst.validation & org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui